# how to get image data from html

Tags: java, android, web

I have html response which contain some image data in it:

```
String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");       
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(response_string, "UTF-8");
Elements els = doc.select("div.blockItem.vevent");
for (Element e : els) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(doc.select("div.blockPhoto > a[href]").get(0).attr("href"));
    String img = doc.select("img[src].photo").get(0).attr("src");
```

In this way I gets relative src of image that I can use to make request for server to get image. But I don't understand - have the response yet the image's data? I tested it by steps below:

- get response
- save response's html as string in memory
- off device's connection to internet
- open the html in WebView

and finally I have seen the page haves images. If response yet have image's data how I should get it, may be it hashed by HttpCient instance that I use to make connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your browser or proxy has cached the images, so switching off your internet connection did not show any effect.

Look at the original HTML source.

If there is an `img` tag like:

```
<img src="pathToImage" />
```

then the image is not part of the response.

If there is a tag like:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM0AAAD .... etc"/>
```

then the image is part of the response.
In that case, you would have to Base64-decode the data to convert it to an image.